# Finite Almost Simple Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request

I want to study finite almost simple groups but I am not sure which would be the best texts to look at. Can someone please refer me to some books that teach the theory of finite almost simple groups?

Comment: That's a very specific topic with answers ranging from beginners abstract algebra text books to papers. what level are you looking for?  i.e.what is your literacy in group theory? simple group theory?

Comment: I just want something which gives an introductory to finite almost simple groups. I have only done an undergraduate and honours level course in abstract algebra. I have not been introduced to any concepts of finite almost simple groups as yet

Comment: I don't think there is much general theory of almost simple groups. The finite almost simple groups are essentially known, because finite simple groups have been classified, and we know all of their automorphism groups. So really, you need to learn about the automorphism groups of the finite simple groups, which I am afraid is a big topic, and would involve learning basic properties of the finite groups of Lie type.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I am currently doing my master's degree. I have been researching pronormal Hall subgroups for the past month, and I have not found any open problems on it so far. I think trying to study the pronormality of Hall $\pi$-subgroups of finite almost simple groups will be a be task and would be of PhD level nature. I will just try to find out general relations of pronormal Hall subgroups of finite groups in the meantime

Comment: A decent option might be "The Finite Simple Groups" by  Robert Wilson.

Answer (score 1):

By the Schreier conjecture, now generally accepted as a corollary of the classification of finite simple groups, the outer automorphism group of a finite simple group is a solvable group. Thus a finite almost simple group is an extension of a *solvable* group by a simple group. This is how far one can get, since it is very general.